# What is the difference between .stream() and Stream.of?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Which is the best way to create a stream out of a collection:

```
    final Collection<String> entities = someService.getArrayList();
```

1. `entities.stream();`
2. `Stream.of(entities);`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The second one does not do what you think it does! It does **not** give you a stream with the elements of the collection; instead, it will give you a stream with a single element, which is the collection itself (not its elements).

If you need to have a stream containing the elements of the collection, then you must use `entities.stream()`.

Comment: if he turns the `entities` to an array, it will have a matter

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes, `Stream.of(...)` would work if `entities` would be an array, but in aurelius' question it is a `Collection`, not an array.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko: if `entities` is an array, the recommended way to construct a stream is `Arrays.stream(entities)` as otherwise, you risk to get a stream of a single array element, depending on the circumstances. `Stream.of` is intended for elements directly named in the invocation. Of course, if you *want* a single element stream, `Stream.of(…)` is the right choice.

Comment: @Holger Actually, `Stream.of(array)` will give you a stream with the elements of the array, not a stream with the array as a single element (the same as `Arrays.stream(array)`) - arrays are automatically "unpacked" when passed to a varargs method.

Comment: @Jesper: the outcome differs, depending on which type is inferred. Or, in other words, `Stream.<String>of(array)` will produce a different outcome as `Stream.<String[]>of(array)`. We got used to the limited type inference for chained method invocation we have today, but even today, using `Stream.of` for existing arrays will backfire when it is an array of primitive type and `Arrays.stream` semantics was actually desired…

Comment: @Holger Yes. But if you're writing `Stream.<String[]>of(array)` then you're already deliberately specifying that you want a stream with string arrays as elements, that's not something you would do by accident.

Comment: @Jesper: the explicitly written types were examples for the otherwise invisibly inferred types. As said, this appears to be no issue today (unless primitive arrays are involved), as streams are usually composed of chained invocations and the currently limited type inference stops at chained invocations. But developers should think ahead. There is a way to expression the intention without ambiguity, `Arrays.stream`, so there’s no reason not to it…

Comment: @Holger, I know, and I am not disagreeing with you, on the contrary.

Answer (score 7):

1)

```
Stream<String> stream1 = entities.stream()
```

2)

```
Stream<Collection<String>> stream2 = Stream.of(entities)
```

So use 1, or for 2

```
Stream<String> stream3 = Stream.of("String1", "String2")
```

Answer (score 4):

We can take a look at the source code:

```
/**
 * Returns a sequential {@code Stream} containing a single element.
 *
 * @param t the single element
 * @param <T> the type of stream elements
 * @return a singleton sequential stream
 */
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Streams.StreamBuilderImpl<>(t), false);
}

/**
 * Returns a sequential ordered stream whose elements are the specified values.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of stream elements
 * @param values the elements of the new stream
 * @return the new stream
 */
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs") // Creating a stream from an array is safe
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values);
}
```

As for `Stream.of()`, when the input variable is an **array**, it will call the second function, and  return a stream containing the elements of the array. When the input variable is a list, it will call the first function, and your input collection will be treated as a single element, not a collection.

So the right usage is :

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3,4,5,7,8,9);
List<Integer> listRight = list.stream().map(i -> i*i).collect(Collectors.toList());

Integer[] integer = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);

List<Integer> listRightToo = Stream.of(integer).map(i ->i*i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I myself keep getting confused about this so I might as well leave this here for future reference:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.Arrays.*;
import static java.util.stream.Stream.*;

class Foo {
    void foo() {
        Stream<Foo> foo; 

        foo =     of(new Foo(), new Foo());
     // foo = stream(new Foo(), new Foo()); not possible

        foo =     of(new Foo[]{new Foo(), new Foo()});
        foo = stream(new Foo[]{new Foo(), new Foo()});

        Stream<Integer> integerStream; 

        integerStream =     of(1, 2);
     // integerStream = stream(1, 2); not possible

        integerStream =     of(new Integer[]{1, 2});
        integerStream = stream(new Integer[]{1, 2});

        Stream<int[]> intArrayStream =     of(new int[]{1, 2}); // count = 1!
        IntStream intStream          = stream(new int[]{1, 2}); // count = 2!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Stream.of()** is generic whereas Arrays.stream is not:
**Arrays.stream()** method only works for primitive arrays of int[], long[], and double[] type, and returns IntStream, LongStream and DoubleStream respectively. For other primitive types,
**Arrays.stream()** won’t work. On the other hand, **Stream.of()** returns a generic Stream of type T (Stream).
Hence, it can be used with any type.