# Stream's limit is not working for a Stream based on a char array

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why doesn't the below code limit the output to first three chars only?

```
 String vowelOne = "aaebcd";

 Stream
    .of(vowelOne.toCharArray())
    .limit(3)       
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
  aaebcd
```

I want the output to be:

```
  aae
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874242/stream-vs-stream-of/39874305 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471799/convert-a-string-to-a-java-util-streamcharacter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888429/how-can-i-create-a-stream-from-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stream.of(char[])` produces a `Stream` of a single `char[]` element (just like `Arrays.asList()` for a primitive array would produce a `List` of a single element), so `limit(3)` doesn't truncate the `Stream`, and you are printing the entire `char[]` (which you can also see from the fact that all the characters are printed in a single line even though you use `println`).

Try :

```
vowelOne.chars() // this returns an IntStream of the characters of the input String
        .limit(3)
        .forEach(i->System.out.println((char)i)); // without the casting to char, you'll
                                                  // get the numeric value of the first 3
                                                  // characters
```

Output :

```
a
a
e
```

Comment: I would go with codePoints() here instead of chars().

Answer (score 1):

Generally codePoints() instead of chars() is better and it handles surrogate pairs too. I have to admit this might be too much for your case in the question.

```
private static String firstN(String input, int limit) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    input.codePoints().limit(limit).forEach(builder::appendCodePoint);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: That leads to the question what `limit` refers to. Even code points aren’t conceptual characters, i.e. you still might split right in the middle of a character consisting of multiple code points. By the way, the `.mapToObj(i -> i)` is obsolete, performing a boxing operation just to do an unboxing right in the next step.

Comment: @Holger indeed. I immediately thought about devanagari letters that have multiple code points. For the simple cases like French and Swedish letters, Normalization needs to be applied first, for the devanagari letters I have no idea to be honest. Yes that map was a bad copy/paste, thx.

Comment: Note that you can make it a cleaner `forEach`less solution using `collect`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20268845/2711488).

Answer (score 0):

As Eran mentioned, `Stream.of(char[])` will produce a `Stream<char[]>`, not a `Stream<char>` as you need it to be. There are additional methods to circumvent this. You either need an array of the boxed type `Character[]`

```
static Character[] toCharacterArray(String s) {
    Character[] array = new Character[s.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       array[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

and use it like this

```
Stream
    .of(toCharacterArray(vowelOne))
    .limit(3)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you could use `String.split("")` to create a `String[]`

```
String vowelOne = "aaebcd";

Stream
    .of(vowelOne.split(""))
    .limit(3)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Both methods result in

```
a
a
e
```

Comment: you have just created an array of each character and saved it in String[] then you limited the number of arrays to.
It would work but don't u think that you've just complicated it rather than simply entering a stream of chars, its messy tbh.

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Where do I save each character in a `String[]`?

Comment: vowelOne.split("") -> will create a String[a], String[a], String[e], String[b], String[c], String[d]

Comment: If you're going to create an additional array of Characters in order to have a `Stream<Character>`, you'd better of using `IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> arr[i]).moreStreamOps(....)` directly.

Comment: Of course the other solutions are better. The point of this was only to *demonstrate* that the desired behaviour is not shown with primitive arrays but rather with the boxed version, i.e. `Character[]` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: If you really want a `Stream<Character>`, using `string.chars().mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char)i))` would be straight-forward… Note that the behavior is merely a matter of overload resolution, i.e. you can exhibit the same behavior with non-primitive array too by using `Stream. <Character[]>of(toCharacterArray(vowelOne)) .limit(3) .forEach(System.out::println);` but since there is no specialized `println(Character[])`, the not so expressive `toString()` output of the array type will be used.